# Is old Bailey's Irish Cream safe to drink?

Tags: food-safety

Will it poison a person to accidentally drink some Bailey's Irish Cream that is way past the expiration date? I am wondering if it will make me ill?

Answer (score 1):

Does it smell off? Has the bottle been opened? More than a year past the expiration date?

- If not, cheers!
- Else use common sense. If in doubt, ditch it.

But it WILL make you ill if you drink too much ;-)

Comment: Also - consider if you (or anyone else who will be drinking it) is immunocompromised or otherwise in bad health.

Comment: Excellent point. That's where the common sense should kick in.

Comment: This is more anecdote than Answer, but it's an additional potential complication with much-too-old Irish Cream. My boyfriend was very happy when his grandmother gave him a lot of liquor when she was cleaning out a cupboard. Included in the haul was a very large unopened bottle of Bailey's, one of his favorites. He got out glasses with ice, opened the bottle, tipped it over to pour it out... and nothing came out. The whole bottle had congealed solid. But if it's gotten the point of being that curdled, you aren't likely to want to drink it anyway :)